# IIS - Internet Explorer session (or something else) timeouts after 2/3 minutes?

Tags: asp.net, angular, internet-explorer, iis

We have an app, built in Angular with backend in ASP.NET Web API.
The Angular app lives in a IIS website and the API lives in i virtual catalog under that webiste, so they have two different web.config.
The Angular site has windows authentication and the API page also has windows authentication but also ASP.NMET Impersonation.
The sessionstate timeout is set to 15 minutes.

Our problem is this:
When we open the start page, the app opens up and signs the user in through a call to the API. Works fine. If we click on a button to fetch data from the API right away it works. The data is fetched as it should.
However, if we wait 2-3 minutes before clicking the button, the API returns status 401, and the form to sign in with my AD account shows up, and even if I type the correct username and password it won't work.
If I refresh the page and click the button right away, it works again.

And this problem is only happening in Internet Explorer (version 11).
In Chrome it does not matter how long time we wait before clicking the button, it works all the time.

So it seems that Internet Explorer time out after a couple of minutes.

Anyone experienced somethin similiar?